# Python hex decoding shows wrong result for special charters

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, decoding

I tried to decode a hex string but special characters.

When I run

```
codecs.decode("5469eb73746f2026204b53484d5220666561742e205661737379", "hex")
```

I get `b'Ti\xebsto & KSHMR feat. Vassy'`

but I want `Tiësto & KSHMR feat. Vassy`

I checked the Hex code online but it is correct. Do I need another function or do I just miss one step?

Comment: I used `print(codecs.decode("5469eb73746f2026204b53484d5220666561742e205661737379", "hex"))` and get `b'Ti\xebsto & KSHMR feat. Vassy'`

Comment: You have a byte value, yes, so decode it to Unicode first.

Comment: Please, in future, include the *full* output you got; the `b'..'` prefix there told me that you are using Python 3, not Python 2 as I initially had to assume (statistically speaking Python 2 would have been more likely).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You decoded the hex value to a *`bytes` object*. If you expected (Unicode) text, decode the bytes with a valid encoding; you appear to have either Latin 1 or Windows Codepage 1252 data here:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.decode("5469eb73746f2026204b53484d5220666561742e205661737379", "hex")
b'Ti\xebsto & KSHMR feat. Vassy'
>>> _.decode('latin1')
'Tiësto & KSHMR feat. Vassy'
```

Comment: @JoranBeasley: `str.encode()` and `bytes.decode()` are entirely consistent in Python 3. You need to use `codecs.encode()` / `codecs.decode()` to get to the [transforming codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) such as `'hex'`.